# Having hard time to publish files to Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Sorry if my question seems dumb. I've started using Eclipse Ganymede 3.4 this week and having hard time publishing my projects to the web app server.

First of all you need to know this issue:
i installed my Tomcat 6.0.18 from Netbeans that i use for PHP and J2SE project. While i can start that server from either Netbeans or Eclipse, it can not start manually for some reason even though i setup my JAVA_HOME correctly pointing to jdk/bin it's saying it's a jre. it a bit weird but i can use the IDE to get going. i did some research on the net and find out that eclipse doesn't publish to tomcat.

In fact i always develop by having a local copy on other drive than C where XP is installed and publish to a server installed on C.

So where i need to find a way to publish to Tomcat under C.
It there any simple way to do that?

Please share your experience.

Thanks for reading

Ps : i know that i can use Netbeans but i'ld like to use Eclipse and use its wysiwyg
thanks!

Comment: Could you please a bit reformat your question?

Comment: Use the Windows installer of Tomcat to set up a separate TC instance. It will provide a notification icon too so you can start/stop TC easily.

Comment: Eclipse Galileo (3.5) was released this week. Unless you need Ganymede for old/incompatible plugins, you might as well upgrade - there are new features, and I've found Galileo much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTP (Web Tools Platform) should get you what you need.  It's a set of Eclipse plugins which includes a one to start/stop/debug Tomcat and publish to a local Tomcat installation.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

You can download a version of Eclipse that already includes WTP: [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php).

Comment: or you just go to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and download "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" which offers eclipse with WTP and other plugins in one (huge) package.

Comment: sorry for the late feedback my internet connection has failed me.I'm using galileo now and evrything seems to be working.for now :) thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

I admit this is not the best practice for a general case, but in my local development environment I created a separate Tomcat environment and I simply store the project itself in this Tomcat's webapps directory. This way the 'deployment' is implicit and instant.

Of course when I need to do changes in the code which cannot be incrementally added during a debug session, I have to restart the Tomcat.

Comment: -1 from me.  I would not recommend that anybody use the Tomcat webapps this way, even if it "works".  Any decent IDE should be able to handle the deployment issue in a way that doesn't require this measure.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your downvote. Emphasis on 'should'.