# eclipse galileo is failling to publish to tomcat on mac!

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat, springsource

i've posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052704/having-hard-time-to-publish-files-to-tomcat-from-eclipse) sometime ago and found the solution by downloading the new eclipse 3.5 (galileo).i believe this is a difference case since 
1- i'm on a macbook pro now os x 10.5.0
2- using the springsource tool suite 2.2 (which is base on eclipse galileo 3.5.1 i think)
i registered tomcat successfully and can start and stop it from the ide.
i have a bash script to start and stop it.
i have set my environment variables in the launchd.conf like so

> setenv JAVA_VERSION 1.6
>   setenv JRE_HOME /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/
>   setenv CATALINA_BASE /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20
>   setenv CATALINA_HOME /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20
>   setenv CATALINA_TMPDIR /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/temp

i just created a small jsp project and run it (run on server) 
i have the 404 status on the browser and nothing in the webapps folder of the tomcat.

so is something i forgot to do?should i add the JAVA_HOME variable?
thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it.now using maven plugin cargo.and it's fine